# Besides ? and *, what other wildcards are allowed in conditional formatting?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

The [google help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on conditional formatting of cells in google sheets has a small section on wildcards but only talks about ? and * (and how to escape them).  Are other wildcards allowed?  I have cells that look like:

```
some text
1.2.3 more text
4.5.6 even more
another section
7.8.9 stuff
```

I want to have the cells **without** numbers be bold.  In the conditional formatting, I can choose "text does not contain" and I want to specify "digit" as a wildcard.  Standard regexp doesn't seem to work.  I've tried `[0-9]`, `:d`, `#`, `\d`.

Google help doesn't list anything else so I'm guessing no other wildcards are supported other than `?` and `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like yourself, I was unable to find any additional wildcards beyond what is specified [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413), the "?" and "*" wildcards.

However, a great feature of Google Sheets is the ability to use custom formulas in combination with custom formatting, at which point the only limit is requiring your custom formula evaluates to a "truthy" (true or false like value).

Here is how you could implement what you are looking for - "Custom formula is":

```
=REGEXMATCH(FIRST_COLUMN:FIRST_COLUMN,"^[^\d]+$")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this too:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+")), , "♦"))<>"", 1))
```

[image: 0]